# Which res folder will be used in 1920*1080 in Android?

Tags: android, dpi, hdpi, highdpi

FHD(Full HD) is 1920*1080.

Which the res folder would be used in FHD and what's the dpi value should be set?

Comment: It really depends on the screen size. Try [ScreenInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jotabout.screeninfo&hl=en), it will tell you everything you need for the screen information.

Comment: @Wenhui the screen of the phone is 5.0".

Comment: It is the same as HTC Droid DNA, so it should be either normal-xxhdpi or sw430dp

Comment: @Wenhui That is to say,if I want to add the picture resources to the android project , I should put them into the drawable-xxhdpi or drawable-sw430dp folder? Is that right? Please give me more informations about the android screeninfo , I want to study it. Thanks very much!!

Comment: Yes, that is right. If you want to learn more about this, read this [post](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: @Wenhui I am confused about the sw430dp. How to calculate the 430 ?

Comment: According to http://pixeldensitycalculator.com/ then 1920x1080 on a 5" screen is 440 dpi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Smallest width` is configured by manufacturer, so it may be varied. For instance, Nexus 7 and Kindle Fire HD both have 1280x800 screen resolution, but the smallest width of N7 is 600dp, while Kindle Fire HD is 533dp.

Here is a way to calculate this:

`If 480x800 is mdpi(160) for 5 inch device, the screen dpi(screenDPI) of the device with resolution 1080X1920 is 160*(1080/480)=360 (NOTE: manufacturer might change this number). Then the smallestWidth = 1080/(screenDPI/160).`

Use [Configuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html) to find out all the information of the device.

Comment: I can't find the xxhdpi from the android document. If I make drawable-xxhdpi new folder ,and put the resources into the folder , could the android System find the resources ?

Comment: Yes, android will find the resource only if the device is running Jelly Bean.

Comment: how to calculate the 430 ? Thanks very much !! I had read many documents ,but I have more confused ,now .

Comment: Do you know the manufacturer how to configure the SmallestWidth and where could I find the way to calculate smallestWidth ? I read the configuration link ,but i cannot find it .

Comment: [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#smallestScreenWidthDp) is the source.

Comment: About the sw430dp, how to gee the qualifier? Thanks .I use the for formula like this:  firstly, i get the dpi: dpi = root(1920*1920+1080*1080)/5 = 440.5 , then I use the formula to get the samllesetWidth : dp=1080/(dpi/160)=1080/(440.5/160) = 392.2. But I can't get the 430. Am I wrong ? Please help me!Thanks.

Comment: No, nothing is wrong. The time I answer your question, I was guessing 432dp ( not sure about the screen dpi at that time), but sw430dp is still going to work when the device smallestWidth is 440.5 because 440.5 > 430.

Comment: The dpi is 440.5 and the dpi is fixed on the phone which I described, so the value won't be changed forever. Is that right ?

Comment: Firstly, i get the **dpi**: 

**dpi** = root(1920*1920+1080*1080)/5 = 440.5

Then I use the formula to get the **samllestWidth** : 

samllestWidth=1080/(dpi/160)=1080/(440.5/160) = 392.2

So the **smallestWidth** is 393dp

But if the manufacturer set the **dpi** to 480 , the **smallestWidth** will be :

  smallestWidth = 1080/(480/160) = 360dp                               .Right ?

Comment: With that resolution on a 5" device, dpi is 302.

Comment: Why is kindle fire 533dp and N7 600dp? They have the same resolution (800x1280) and the same screen size (7"), so the same dpi (216) - how come you say they have different "smallest width"?

Comment: As I see it, the dp is not 533 or 600, its 593 for both. Am I wrong, and if so, why? 
Calc: 800 / (216/160) = 800 / 1.35 = 593

Comment: Very nice explanation. Great sw calculation formula.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the screen size because a 7' screen with FHD will not have the same dpi as a 17' screen with FHD. to know DPI I use this calculator :

http://members.ping.de/~sven/dpi.html

and for the folders please try the actual google documentation it is pretty complete:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

hope it helps!

Comment: Dear @jumojer, what do you think about the Wenhui's answer ?

Comment: @Jerikc XIONG Well i don't know about the drawable/xxhdpi but since your screen is 5", it as a 440.5 dpi and your drawables should be contained in, at least, drawable/xhdpi or in drawable/xxhdpi as Wenhui said (if it exists, I'm pretty sure it does).

Comment: Yes, Google adds support of xxhdpi from JB. Source [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_XXHIGH)

Comment: thanks about the info, so to answer @Jerikc XIONG 's question : in the Drawable/xxhdpi folder or sw430dp and the dpi of the screen is 440.5